# Mutate case_when in R to create a column of time periods per participant

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have tested participants at three points in time. I have the dates at which they were tested. I want to make a column which levels are first, second, and third. Each participant has three dates, so they are all different per participant. The data looks like this:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), time_tested = c("2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", 
"2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11", 
"2022-02-11", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-10", 
"2022-02-10", "2022-02-10", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-13", 
"2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", 
"2022-02-08", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

and this is the result I want:

```
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), time_tested = c("2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", 
"2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11", 
"2022-02-11", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-10", 
"2022-02-10", "2022-02-10", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-13", "2022-02-13", 
"2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-05", "2022-02-08", "2022-02-08", 
"2022-02-08", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11", "2022-02-11"), period = c("first", 
"first", "first", "second", "second", "second", "third", "third", 
"third", "first", "first", "first", "second", "second", "second", 
"third", "third", "third", "first", "first", "first", "second", 
"second", "second", "third", "third", "third")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-27L))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please don’t use images of data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Questions should be reproducible. This makes it easy for other who may want to help, copy data easily. Check out stack overflow guidance [mre] and [ask]. Include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as `df <- data.frame(…)` where … are your variables and values or use `dput(head(df))`. [Good overview on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table::rleid` to get the group ids, and `ordinal` function from package english to convert it to ordinal.

##### Base R

```r
df$period <- as.numeric(ave(df$time_tested, df$id, FUN = data.table::rleid))
df$english <- english::ordinal(df$period)
```

#### tidyverse

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(period = data.table::rleid(time_tested), 
         english = english::ordinal(period))
```

output

```r
   id time_tested period english
1   1  2022-02-05      1   first
2   1  2022-02-05      1   first
3   1  2022-02-05      1   first
4   1  2022-02-08      2  second
5   1  2022-02-08      2  second
6   1  2022-02-08      2  second
7   1  2022-02-11      3   third
8   1  2022-02-11      3   third
9   1  2022-02-11      3   third
10  2  2022-02-08      1   first
11  2  2022-02-08      1   first
12  2  2022-02-08      1   first
13  2  2022-02-10      2  second
14  2  2022-02-10      2  second
15  2  2022-02-10      2  second
16  2  2022-02-13      3   third
17  2  2022-02-13      3   third
18  2  2022-02-13      3   third
19  3  2022-02-05      1   first
20  3  2022-02-05      1   first
21  3  2022-02-05      1   first
22  3  2022-02-08      2  second
23  3  2022-02-08      2  second
24  3  2022-02-08      2  second
25  3  2022-02-11      3   third
26  3  2022-02-11      3   third
27  3  2022-02-11      3   third
```